# Codewars Kata - 4th Kyu - Codewars style ranking system - "+1 problem"

Tags: javascript, arrays

I thought that this kata will be very cool and easy to get back to js after a break.
I was so wrong lol.
So the URL to kata is here with all of the logic and math informations, i'll put the necessary ones below.

URL:
https://www.codewars.com/kata/51fda2d95d6efda45e00004e/train/javascript

Code:

```
class User {
    constructor() {
        this.rank = -8;
        this.progress = 0;
    this.rankTable=[-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
    this.rankIndicator=0;
    }
  
    incProgress(rankOfActivity) {
    if (rankOfActivity == 0 || rankOfActivity > 8 || rankOfActivity < -8) throw new error("Rank input out of range");
        if (rankOfActivity <= this.rank - 2) return;
    let diff = this.rankTable.indexOf(rankOfActivity)-this.rankTable.indexOf(this.rank);
    if (diff==0) this.progress+=3;
    else if(diff==-1) this.progress+=1;
    else if(this.rank!=8){
      this.progress+= 10*diff*diff;
      while(this.progress>=100 && this.rank<8){
        this.progress-=100;
        this.rankIndicator++;
        this.rank=this.rankTable[this.rankIndicator];
      }
    }
    if (this.rank==8) this.progress=0;
  }
}
```

> Completing an activity that is ranked one ranking lower than the user's will be worth 1 point

After i saw that, my point of view was:
If the difference between activity rank and user's rank was -1 ,for example:

User's rank is -2 (index 6 in rankTable array)

Activity ranked at -3 (index 5 in rankTable array)

The difference would be 5-6 = -1

So it should add up 1 point of progress, and it looks like it doesn't do that and i cant figure it out why it doesn't add up.

Here are bunch of errors to show that it happens on any rank.

> After applying rank of -1 the progress was expected to be 21, but was actually 20

> After applying rank of 3 the progress was expected to be 61, but was actually 60

> After applying rank of 8 the progress was expected to be 51, but was actually 50

Comment: @ulou
Nah, the kata says that min is -8 max is 8. So you can progress from -8 to 8 excluding 0

Answer (score 0):

```
    //...
    //if (rankOfActivity <= (this.rank - 2)) return;
    //bug
    let diff = (this.rankTable.indexOf(rankOfActivity)) - (this.rankTable.indexOf(this.rank));
    
    if (diff <=-2)return;//
    //fixed
    //...
```

Personally, i do not like array and `indexOf` use here. Using a rank counter of [0 to 15] would be a little better.